# Is it possible to break on a switch statement only when it doesn't hit the default case?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

THere's a switch statement with 8 cases inside, and I want to see when it hits.

Unfortunately before hitting, it hits default around 10 times.

Now I either break at switch, press F10, and continue when it hits default, or I set breakpoints on each case but default.

Any chance I can change this?

It's not possible to change the switch statement or the way the methods around it work (unfortunately).

Edit: I'm looking for something like a conditional breakpoint, but the condition being  `switchOnThis == (default case)`

Comment: Fair question: but AFAIK, no: you can't do that

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily any easier than just setting break points on each case you care about, but you could set a conditional break on the `switch` with the condition that it match one the cases.

Comment: Do you want a conditional break in visual studio?

Comment: You can break on the case entry independently.

Comment: A question: if one of the cases hit, where would you want it to break?

Comment: The answer below by @OmG is how I would have done it. Alternatively, if you want to break outside the switch (unclear what you prefer), you could add a simple if statement to test the same thing as the conditional break (test == 1..., etc.) and then break inside that block.

Comment: @MarcGravell You can with conditional breaks in VS; see @ OmG's answer.

Comment: @EmilioVicari The exact spot isn't too important to me, just that it break at all.

Comment: OK, I see. I came up with something. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a conditional breakpoint like the following. First suppose you have the following `switch\case`:

```
int test = 0;
// value of the test will be set here
switch (test)
{
    case 1:
        // case 1
        break;
    case 4:
        // case 4
        break;
    case 5:
        // case 5
        break;
    // up to 8 cases
    default:
        break;
}
```

Then set a breakpoint in the editor, and right-click on it. You can see the `Conditions...` on the menu. click on it, and write the conditions:

[image]

You can set the conditions like the following:

[image]

The conditional berakpoint breaks when one of the cases will be happened.

Comment: This doesn't really change the way it works, since I stil have to cover all the cases. Conditional breakpoints are great for breaking on a particular iteration, but that's not actually the case here.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with something.

You could take advantage of the side effects of breakpoint conditions this way:

1. Place a breakpoint before (or at) the `switch` statement. The condition on this breakpoint should "raise a flag" (e.g. create a file) and evaluate to anything other than `true`, so that the breakpoint is not hit.
2. Place a breakpoint in the `default` case. The condition on this breakpoint should "lower the flag" (e.g. delete the same file) and should also not evaluate to `true`.
3. Place a breakpoint at the instruction following the end of the `switch` block. Condition on this breakpoint should simply check the flag (e.g. check that file exists) and return `true` if the flag is still raised (i.e. a case other than default was hit). **This is where execution will break when one of the case labels other than default is hit**.

I tried this with the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num = 0;
    bool hit = false;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Insert an integer value (1-8 hits, 100 to quit):");
        num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (num) // breakpoint 1 here
        {
            case 1: hit = true; break;
            case 2: hit = true; break;
            case 3: hit = true; break;
            case 4: hit = true; break;
            case 5: hit = true; break;
            case 6: hit = true; break;
            case 7: hit = true; break;
            case 8: hit = true; break;
            default: hit = false; break; // breakpoint 2 here
        }

        Console.WriteLine("hit = " + hit.ToString()); // breakpoint 3 here
    } while (num != 100);

}
```

I placed conditional breakpoint 1 at `switch (num)` with the following condition (it evaluates to nothing, thus it never breaks):

```
System.IO.File.Create(@"somefile.txt").Close()
```

Breakpoint 2 at the `default` case with the following condition (also evaluates to nothing):

```
System.IO.File.Delete(@"somefile.txt")
```

Finally, breakpoint 3 at `Console.WriteLine("hit =...`, with condition:

```
System.IO.File.Exists(@"somefile.txt")
```

It works as expexted, i.e. it breaks after the `switch` block only if the `default` case was not hit.

In order for this to work **you need to configure the debugging environment to use both native and managed compatibility**. Go to:

```
Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General
```

and check `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` and `Use Native Compatibility Mode`.

The create/delete file idea is the only one I could come up with that has side effects and doesn't require any change to your code.

Comment: Really nice idea. Doesn't help me in this particular case, since a window will open as soon as the switch hits somewhere that's not default, but I'll keep it in mind for future usages :)

Answer (score 0):

Add another `switch` with the same cases before your existing `switch`:

```
switch (condition)
{
  case 1:
  case 2:
  ...
  case 8:
    break;  // <-- set the breakpoint here
}
```